# Get e-mail notification if backup job fails on Azure

Tags: azure

How can I configure through the web interface to get an e-mail notification if the backup of my Azure VM fails?

This seems to be such a basic functionality so I'm frustrated I can't find this.  When I search the net I find guides to do this through powershell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far it's not possible although planned. You can vote for this feature in the link below:

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/258995-azure-backup-and-scdpm/suggestions/6531898-email-notification-alerts-for-azure-backup

As a workaround, Azure Backup Agent writes in Event Logs (CloudBackup/Operational) and you can use Task Scheduler to send e-mail notifications after specific event IDs are written.

Here's nice tutorial if you need details on how to do this:

http://www.itgeekrambling.co.uk/azure-azure-backup-and-email-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article with a script that will generate a complete mail-report of the Azure Backups.
It specifies name, status (completed/failed/aborted), start time, stop time, uploaded data and total backup data.

http://blog.jocha.se/tech/azure-backup-mail-report-script